# Can I send a push notifiction from ios to ios, without a server?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my research, I see this question has been asked a few times, but generally the response seems to be somewhere between "why would you do this?", "it's theoretically possible but not practical" and "yes, but there are technical issues".

I have a real world case where push messages will originate on an iphone and terminate on another iphone. The app is designed for family/couples, who can scan each other's phones to get device tokens, and store them within the app.

Most of the questions I found around this subject are pretty old and mentioned Apple's requirement to keep the APNS connection open for as long as possible, however I am not sure if this still holds with the HTTP2 interface that is now available.

Another comment is that it is difficult, but I'm not worried about that - I've written the server side for APNS and HTTP2, so it's "just" a case of rewriting it in objective C.

I realize that certificates are an issue, and might require users to update regularly to keep it working, although I wonder if there's some way to store them and just have the app update them automatically, without needing to update the whole app. No biggie either way.

So my question is, in 2018, is it possible to implement an iphone to iphone push notification and (taking into account what I said above), are there reasons not to? I could easily make a server for it, but the less third parties the message has to pass through, the better it is from a privacy/transparency perspective, hence peer to peer would be the ideal option.

Comment: The notification would still go via Apple's Push Notification Service, it's just the origin of the message is coming from the device, as apposed to some server

Comment: I did the exact same thing but using a third party called onesignal using "player_id"s. You might want to check that out.

Comment: @bseh I am trying to avoid using third parties!

Comment: @MadProgrammer - this is correct, but from the privacy/transparency perspective Apple is a much more trusted entity than a random new startup. I know I can't do true peer to peer, I just want to know if I can do it without any third parties (outside of Apple, who are already an involved third party as they make the phone).